# telerik:RadDiagramShape not show inner element in coded ui test

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, coded-ui-tests

I have a telerik:RadDiagramShape which i placed two Images inside it. 
but coded UI Test Builder does not recognize the inner element. how can I fix the code so that coded UI Test Builder detects the images? 
here is my xaml code:

```
<telerik:RadDiagramShape>

     <Grid>
         <Image Source="Images/refresh.png" Name="imgRefresh"
            Stretch="Uniform" >

           <Image.RenderTransform>
             <RotateTransform Angle="-45" CenterX="10" CenterY="10" />
           </Image.RenderTransform>
      </Image>


      <Image Name="imgState" Source="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
           VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" Height="20" Stretch="Uniform"
           Grid.Row="0"
            MouseUp="imgState_MouseUp" Cursor="Hand" />
  </Grid>
</telerik:RadDiagramShape>
```

any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed the Telerik Coded UI assembly (http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/coded-ui-support.html")?    Also, have you tried manually creating the object since you know the properties to use?

Comment: Sorry, @kamran, I just realized that we'd already covered that in a previous question.

Answer (score 0):

The UITestControl object should be able to be found if you're defining it properly, i.e., specifying the right search and filter properties.  For example, in the code above, you can set the image as

```
HtmlImage imgState = new HtmlImage();
imgState.SearchProperties["name"] = "imgState";
return imgState;
```

If that doesn't work, try to set up some identifying properties for the combo box, like an ID or name, and then work your way down.

```
HtmlComboBox parent = new HtmlComboBox();
parent.SearchProperties["name"] = "<myName>";
HtmlImage target = new HtmlImage(parent);
target.SearchProperties["name"] = "imgState";
return target;
```

Of course, both of these objects could be defined in any of the UITestControl classes, depending on your situation.  Coded UI is all about properly defining your page objects, so once you've determined the best way to find them on whatever page you're looking at, your tests will start to fall in place.

Comment: thanks @Rayan. I followed the steps that you mentioned with no result.  As second thought I Used "Inspect Object" tool to detect Images, but it only found RadDiagramShape and not able to find inner Images.